Are some superpositions caused by measurement?
From the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, we know that we can't know both the position and momentum of a particle, does this mean that measuring the position puts the momentum in a superposition? Or does it just mean that we will never know because we've interacted with it and destroyed that information (the momentum before observation)?

..."puts the momentum in a superposition..." A superposition of what? You have to specify the basis first.  If you measure the momentum, then the post-measurement state is an eigenstate of momentum (modulo some comments about momentum eigenstates being non-normalizable), which is not a superposition of momentum eigenstates. However, that state is a superposition of position eigenstates. Every quantum state is a superposition, because you can always choose to expand the state in a basis that doesn't contain the state as an element.

I'm. not writing an answer, because I'm not sure what your actual question is. "Are some superpositions caused by measurement?" is different than "Does this mean that measuring the position puts the momentum in a superposition?" which is different than "Does it just mean that we will never know because we've interacted with it and destroyed that information (the momentum before observation)?" Unfortunately, the questions seem to stem from a set of false premises about what QM is about, so it's hard to answer this question. Can you clarify and/or focus your question?

This is not complicated and your intuition is correct: yes, a measurement of $X$ leaves the system in a superposition of eigenstates of $Y$ if $[X, Y] \neq 0$.

From what you've written it looks like you're thinking that the uncertainty is caused by the act of measurement, in the sense that performing the measurement somehow disturbs the system, and that this makes things uncertain. But it's more fundamental than that. The uncertainty is embedded into the underlying physics - in a certain sense, the particle (the underlying wavefunction) doesn't simultaneously have precisely defined position and momentum, weather you measure it or not. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4

Not "momentum in superposition", but $\psi$ in superposition of (improper) eigenfunctions of the momentum operator, $\psi_{localized} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c(p)e^{ipx/\hbar}dp/\sqrt{2\pi}$.

A measurement of an observable $A$ collapses the state into one of the eigenstates $|n\rangle$ of $A$. If you measure repeatedly this operator in this basis, you will just get $|n\rangle$, $|n\rangle$, etc (really, the associated eigenvalue).
But there may be another basis and another operator you may want to measure, call it $X$. This $X$ operator has a basis $|\varphi\rangle$ such that every element of $|n\rangle$ can be written as a linear combination of $|\varphi\rangle$ states. This can always be done since all of these live in the same Hilbert space. An example of this would be measuring spin in two different directions. The observables are different, not compatible, yet all in the same Hilbert space. Summarizing, you have
$$|n\rangle = \sum_i c_i |\varphi_i\rangle. $$
So when you measure the observable $X$ you end up getting one of the possible $|\varphi_i\rangle$ states with probability $|c_i|^2$. In this sense, a measurement yields a superposition - but only because you're measuring an incompatible observable.

A few remarks:

You shouldn't think of "being in a superposition" as a meaningful statement about some property of a quantum state (unless you introduce additional qualifiers, give a particular physical meaning to some basis, etc). Every quantum state can be written as a superposition in infinitely many ways. Eg the state $|0\rangle$ can be written as $(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)+(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$, or as $(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)+(|0\rangle-i|1\rangle)$, or in infinitely many other ways. Exactly like you can decompose vectors in an abstract vector space in infinitely many choices of basis.

Measurements cause collapse of the state. Projective measurements (which you often describe in terms of "measuring an observable") collapse the state in the eigenstate corresponding to the measured eigenvalue. So yes, you have a collapse, which creates a specific superposition. But then again, the state was "a superposition" also before the measurement, so this seems a rather moot point.
You can make the statement a bit more meaningful saying that the measurement creates a state that has to be a superposition of different eigenstates of any observable that doesn't commute with the one you're measuring, as pointed out in the comments.



I think your question is as follows:
We see the phenomenon--after measuring the position of a particle, we can't measure the exact value of it's momentum, what we know is just a distribution.
To explain this abnormal phenomenon, we raise two possible theories.

(Classical parlance) When we measure the position, we disturbance the particle, so the momentum changes (as you said "destroyed that information"). Thus we can't measure the exact value of it's momentum.

(Quantum parlance) Measuring the position puts the momentum into a superpositon of eigenstates of momentum. Thus we know just a distribution.


Which theory is right?
My answer is as follows:
The two theories are all right.

Classical parlance treat measurement as disturbance. The peculiarity is that the distuibance cannot be ignored by the improvement of the experimental method. In this way we define how a system is absolutely small, and we call this kind of small system quantum system. In this view, what Quantum Mechanics tell us is just how quantum system interacts with our surveying instrument, not how nature acts.

Quantum parlance treat measurment as wave function collapse. This special physical process causes wave function becomes the eigenstate of position, at the same time a superposition of eigenstates of momentum. In this view, Quantum Mechanics means, to some extent, how nature acts.


Both of these theories describe phenomenon in different patterns. We can't say which is right or wrong. They are all effective.
